How to instance scene in Godot but with C++ module?
I try to rewrite my Gdscript logic to C++ with modules way. There is no any issues if I load resource with line:
Ref<Resource> cpp_sprite = ResourceLoader::load("res://CppSprite.tscn");

But I can not make instance it to scene just as in gdscript do, this line return an error:
CppNode *cpp_sprite_instance = cpp_sprite->instance();

Compiler says: class Resource has no member “instance”. Allright, cpp_sprite is Resource type. But how to flip Resource type to PackedScene?
I checked the docs but there is not too much information about C++ code writing.

I recommend you post to [gamedev.se].

Please post the definition of the RES class.  The error is saying that the RES class doesn't have an instance() method.

@thomas-matthews RES is typedef for Ref<Resource>. In Godot, when I instance a packed scene it get the base class of scene itself, in this case it is CppNode, second line should return with this type. But it is no matter, first I need to convert Resource to PackedScene type. Gdscript doing this under the hood, that means I can, but how?

@user28648854 I haven't used [tag:godot] myself, but could it be that you should use Ref<SpriteFrames> cpp_sprite = ... instead? The base class, Resource, doesn't have many member functions but SpriteFrames has a few.

@ThomasMatthews just as a heads-up, when recommending users post their questions on the Game Development SE, please emphasize that they should delete the copy on StackOverflow first, or flag for a moderator to migrate it. GDSE will usually close questions that have an exact duplicate open on StackOverflow. We do this to try to keep the best answers gathered in one place, and avoid leaving dead ends for future searches. So, it's best to choose a single site that best-matches the expertise needed for the question, and avoid cross-posting.

@ted-lyngmo yes, that is it. I used Resource but I could use PackedScene immediately. Works as expected with Ref<PackedScene>. Confused in ResourceLoader

So on I was wrong with types. ResourceLoader::load can load packed scene straight ahead as PackedScene, not necessary use Resorce class. Solved wtih flip Ref<Resource> to Ref<PackedScene>:
Ref<PackedScene> cpp_sprite = ResourceLoader::load("res://CppSprite.tscn");

